# Add and remove a marker character on click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a marker character to a link when the user clicks it, and remove it when he clicks it a second time.

Here's what I have :

```
$('#text a').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).text(markerTextChar +  $(this).text());
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).text($(this).text().substring(1));
    });
});
```

The marker is added on click, but it is added one more time when I click it to deselect it.

Can you help me fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a event handler with `bind` (or `click`) doesn't remove the old ones.

You could [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) it but this is not needed. Do this instead :

```
$('#text a').click(function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).text($(this).text().substring(1));
   } else {
      $(this).text(markerTextChar +  $(this).text());
       $(this).addClass('clicked');
   } 
});
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Ftw4U/)

---

You might also use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and use `:before` in css to add your char, that would be much cleaner.

css :

```
.clicked:before {
    content: "yourmarker";
}​
```

javascript :

```
$('#text a').click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});​
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zfvj/)

Comment: Can't do it in css, I need it to mark the links before removing all html

Comment: If you can't use CSS, use my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have to unbind first click event do it like this

```
$('#text a').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).text(markerTextChar +  $(this).text());
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).text($(this).text().substring(1));
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. you must use unbind, not try to remove the attribute.